# Solve $|z-i|+|z+i| \le 4$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to solve this equation:

$|z-i|+|z+i| \le 4$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$

I know that this should represent an ellipse, but I just do not see how to get the correct solution (which would be as far as I know $1 = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$

My solution would be:

Since $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we can write $ z = x + iy $

$|x+iy-i|+|x+iy+i| \le 4$

$|x+i(y-1)|+|x+i(y+1)| \le 4$

$ \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2} \le 4$

$ x^2+(y-1)^2+x^2+(y+1)^2 \le 16$

$ x^2+y^2-2y+1+x^2+y^2+2y+1\le 16$

$ 2x^2+2y^2+2\le 16$

$ x^2+y^2+1\le 8$

$ y^2\le 7-x^2$

Which is obviously very different from the correct (?) result.

Comment: Wrong step: $$ \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2} \le 4$$ is not equivalent to $$ x^2+(y-1)^2+x^2+(y+1)^2 \le 16$$

Comment: Jack. Your equation is fine up to where you "lose" the square roots. The line where it says <= 16 is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: squaring the given inequality
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\le 4$$ gives
$$x^2+(y-1)^2+2\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}+x^2+(y+1)^2\le 16$$
can you proceed now?
i have used $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$
squaring again and simplifying we obtain
$$4x^2+3y^2\le 12$$

Comment: ok, if you know a better way then Show us

Comment: can you delete the $-1$ please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Done.

Comment: This is like going from London to Paris via Moscow.

Comment: Moscow is also a wonderful town like Paris

Answer (score 1):

$|z-i|+|z+i| = 4$ is ellipse with focus at $i$ and $-i$. So $|z-i|+|z+i| \le 4$ is interior of this ellipse.

Since $2b =4$ and $e=1$ so $a=\sqrt{3}$. Thus we get $${x^2\over 3} +{y^2\over 4} \leq 1$$

Comment: How is this an answer to the question *"I know that this should represent an ellipse, but I just do not see how to get the correct solution"* ? OP is asking where the error in his calculation is.

Comment: what you are saying is without a proof

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

$${x}^{2}+{\left(y-1\right)}^{2}  \leqslant  16-8 \sqrt{{x}^{2}+{\left(y+1\right)}^{2}}+{x}^{2}+{\left(y+1\right)}^{2}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{{x}^{2}+{\left(y+1\right)}^{2}}  \leqslant  2+\frac{1}{2} y$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow {x}^{2}+{\left(y+1\right)}^{2}  \leqslant  4+2 y+\frac{1}{4} {y}^{2}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow {x}^{2}+\frac{3}{4} {y}^{2}  \leqslant  3$$